# Does the Mimo 720-s touchscreen work with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display, touchscreen

Does the Mimo 720-S work with Windows 7's multi-touch?  Their website doesn't mention anything newer than Vista.  Even though it's a touch, it doesn't mention multi-touch.  Has anyone tried one with windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mimo is single touch and they have drivers for windows 7 on support page.

http://www.mimomonitors.com/pages/customer-support

Comment: While the drivers do work I have found that they are inconsistent at best.  My Mimo 720-S only works with the touchscreen about 1 in 5 or 1 in 10 boots.  Most of the time the touchscreen appears to not be detected.  The driver applet loads and appears in the tray but when I open it there's no hardware listed, as though it can't find the display.  The graphics work perfectly every time, just the touch feature that is flakey.  I'm running Win 7 64-bit.